# Ruby SimpleCov missing one return line

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, simplecov

**This is my class which returns the multiplication of parameters**

```
class NetAssetValue

def calculate_net_asset_value(number_of_shares, price)

    number_of_shares * price
  end

end
```

**And this is my Test**

```
require 'net_asset_value'

require 'test/unit'

class NetAssetValueTest  < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup

    @asset = NetAssetValue.new

  end


  def test_calculate_net_asset_value_for_a_symbol

    assert_equal(100, @asset.calculate_net_asset_value(20,5))

  end

end
```

I am using SimpleCov 0.7.1. The coverage report says the one line in the method is not covered though it is being covered.

It says the coverage is 66.67% and the line

> number_of_shares * price

is not covered But when I debug in RubyMine and place a breakpoint on that line it is being hit.

Need Help on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Where do you call `SimpleCov.start`?

Comment: $:.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'src'))
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
SimpleCov.command_name 'unit tests'

require './src/net_asset_value.rb'
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new('test') do |test|
  test.pattern = 'test/*_test.rb'
  test.verbose = true
  test.warning = true
end

task :default => [:test]

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and insert the contents of your Rakefile there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Simplecov from within `Rake::TestTask` since that task runs the tests in a separate process. See https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/88.

**EDIT**

To clarify: You can certainly use SimpleCov by using a Rakefile, but you can't start (`SimpleCov.start`) it in the Rakefile. You need to do that in the test, e.g. in your test helper.
Keep in mind that `SimpleCov.start` must be called before requiring your production code.